# Under the/a threat of attack

Tags: sentence-meaning, articles, definite-article

How would the meaning of these sentences change if I use the articles in four different ways?

1. Local people used to live under the threat of an attack.
2. Local people used to live under the  threat of (without an)  attack.
3. Local people used to live under a threat of an attack.
4. Local people used to live under a  threat of attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definite article.

Whether you say "threat of attack", or "threat of *an* attack" is irrelevant. Both of these noun phrases are using 'threat' in an abstract way, similar to saying someone has 'guilt' or 'fear'. They are not individual instances of being threatened. They are the names of a unique experience or feeling.

We would only count threats if they were individual instances. For example, if someone was verbally threatened on a daily basis, we might say "they live with constant threats". The threat or fear that the same thing may happen every day is the same threat/fear, and therefore unique, requiring a definite article.

Comment: Alternatively leave the article out altogether. "Local people used to live under threat of an attack" or "Local people used to live under threat of attack".

Comment: @Peter, do you mean if I remove the article before *threat* it's still understood as "the same threat/fear, and therefore unique, requiring a definite article" but the sentence can work without it?

Comment: @AntoniaA, "under threat" means "threatened by" or "threatened with" something. Here "threat" is uncountable, and it means the same with or without "the". Using "a threat" refers to a specific threatening communication (verbal or non-verbal).

Comment: Peter, @Astralbee, said whether I use  "threat of attack", or "threat of an attack" is irrelevant. You used it with and without "an" does the meaning change much with and without "an"?

Comment: @AntoniaA No it doesn't. Peter is correct, it works without an article too, because this use of 'threat' is abstract, as I explained. It doesn't make a difference if you included 'an' because that is within a noun phrase. You can change a noun phrase all you like, you still use it as one.

Comment: @Astralbee, I am trying to think of an example using "a threat" where it would refer to "a specific threatening communication (verbal or non-verbal)".  For example, if I say "She never realised there was a threat of murder", should not it be "the threat of murder" the unique one?